# Get updated row in ASPxGridView.RowUpdating event with composite KeyFieldName

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, devexpress

I'm trying to create a custom edit script for my ASPxGridView. I have a second grid in which I used the code below to obtain the row that has been updated. This, however, doesn't work because my grid has a composite KeyFieldName (because the table it's based on has a primary key made up of two columns). This results in the FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue method always returning -1.

Any ideas on how I could obtain the row some other way?

```
object key = e.Keys[grid.KeyFieldName];
int row = grid.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(key);
```

Edit: The problem actually is that e.Keys[grid.KeyFieldName] returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by saving the keys into an array of objects one by one and passing that array to FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue().

```
object[] key = new object[2];
key[0]= e.Keys["firstKey"];
key[1] = e.Keys["secondKey"];
int row = grid.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(key);
```